# SQL - count and group by, select * from <table>

Tags: sql, group-by, count

I have a table with 27 colums, and I have to count something out of this table, like this:

```
OPP_ID           ACC_ID
--------------------------
1                A
2                B
3                B
4                A
5                C
6                D
7                A
8                E
```

And I need this:

```
OPP_ID           ACC_ID      count
-----------------------------------
1                A             3          
2                B             2
3                B             2
4                A             3
5                C             1
6                D             1
7                A             3
8                E             1
```

So I want to count the ACC_ID and need a new column with the value how often a specific ACC_ID is in the table, e.g. ACC_ID = A is 3 times in the table, so I want in a new column behind every ACC_ID value with A with the value 3.

I already tried this but I can´t find a perfect solution. 
I used the `group by function` but I can´ t output the whole table with select * if I am using the `group by`

Comment: which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I am working with a browser interface, I don´t know which DBMS is behind this interface.
The descriptions stays that I have to use Spark SQL syntax and functions.

Comment: Well, you've got some answers already. Start with Radim Bača's.

Answer (score 3):

Use window functions (if your DBMS support it)

```
SELECT OPP_ID, ACC_ID, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ACC_ID) FROM table
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT A.*, B.[Count]
FROM MyTable A
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT ACC_ID, Count(*) AS [Count]
    FROM MyTable 
    GROUP BY ACC_ID
) B ON B.ACC_ID = A.ACC_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are USING MS SQL Server then try below :

```
SELECT T.OPP_ID, S.ACC_ID, S.COUNT FROM
(
    SELECT ACC_ID, COUNT(*) COUNT FROM #TEMP GROUP BY ACC_ID
) S
INNER JOIN #TEMP T ON T.ACC_ID = S.ACC_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.OPP_ID,A.ACC_ID,COUNT(R) COUNT FROM MYTABLE A INNER JOIN(
SELECT OPP_ID,ACC_ID ,DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ACC_ID ORDER BY OPP_ID) R FROM MYTABLE) B 
ON A.ACC_ID=B.ACC_ID GROUP BY A.ACC_ID,A.OPP_ID
```